# jquery typeahead plugin doesn't work when ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, typeahead

I search all questions about typeahead plugin in this forum and have tried all the ways i can. But i have a problem yet. Im using codeigniter and want to autocomplete by typeahead plugin via ajax. This is my js code:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
}, {
    source: function (query, process) {
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl + 'panel/yazilarim/deneme',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'query=' + query,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                process(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```php
public function deneme() {
    $aranan = $this->input->post("query");
    $sorgu = $this->db->select("ad")->from("kategori")->where("ad LIKE '%" . $aranan . "%' ")->get();

    $sonuclar = $sorgu->result_array();
    $dizi = [];
    foreach ($sonuclar as $sonuc) {
        $dizi[] = $sonuc["ad"];
    }
    echo json_encode($dizi);
}
```

`console.log()` function works well, i can see the result array, but the dropdown menu never appears. I've load bundle and typeahead js files and the css file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you include an example of what your JSON looks like?

Comment: Sure. My console log output looks like this: ["kuaforler","kurslar","kurabiye"...]

Comment: @AlperEratilla Don't use `async: false` as the now deleted answer suggested! You get browser warnings about it's use as it's extremely bad practice

Comment: Which autocomplete library are you using? You either need to invert your logic to make the AJAX call first, or use AJAX functionality that's built in to most libraries.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, yes browser warning me, but when i remove async row, function doesnt works again. What is you suggestion bro?

Comment: Im using typeahead.js @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I updated answer. Please remove downvote.

Comment: @AlperEratilla, please try my answer without removing `async:true`

Comment: @AlperEratilla, please try my answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i implemented typeahead in my CodeIgniter project. Please refer the my working code. In the view page

```
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/typeahead.min.js'); ?>" > </script>
     <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'typeahead',
        remote:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>panel/yazilarim/deneme?query=%QUERY',
        limit : 5
    });
});
 </script>



<div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="member"  class="form-control typeahead" style="width:280px;"  autocomplete="off" >
</div>
```

In the controller

```
public function deneme() {
    $aranan = $this->input->get("query");
    $sorgu = $this->db->select("ad")->from("kategori")->where("ad LIKE '%" . $aranan . "%' ")->get();

    $sonuclar = $sorgu->result_array();
    $dizi = [];
    foreach ($sonuclar as $sonuc) {
        $dizi[] = $sonuc["ad"];
    }
    echo json_encode($dizi);
}
```

I think your controller is right. If it doesn't work please comment the problem below.Remember i use get method.

Comment: Remote method doesn't work for me. I changed my POST s to GET but still doesnt work bro. Am i missing something?

Comment: @AlperEratilla, please view description from my answer.

Comment: Can you copy and paste only my code and try again. And can you also analyse your JSON returns by using firebug in firefox. The above code is a 100% working snippets for my project .

Comment: I copied and pasted bro. No erorrs but get nothing.  I think same sync problem, but i cant figure out why. Looks great

Comment: Please check your response json with firebug.

Comment: In my case, i didn't get down down when my json is wrongly formatted. So i analyze json returns by using firebug in firefox

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return result. Please try this:

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    return process(data);
}
```

Also, set `async:false` property.

> At a very basic level, you use an asynchronous mode when you want the
>   call to occur in the background and a synchronous mode when you want
>   your code to wait until the call has completed.

Here is `asyncronous` version.

```
source: function (query, process) {
   var getData = getData();
   getData.done(function(data){
      return process(data);
    // do stuff with `information` here, not elsewhere.
   });
   function getData(){ 
      return $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl + 'panel/yazilarim/deneme',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'query=' + query,
        dataType: 'JSON'
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Im' trying now bro. I'll imediately tell you result

Comment: Sorry bro. Only runs when async is false, but it makes everything too slow :(

Comment: Difference between `async`  and `sync` is that `sync` does operation in background and don't block the UI thread. If you want everyting more fast, you need to use `multithreading programming`